# How to make the stack of a C program executable?

Tags: c

Is there a way to make the stack of a C program executable through compilation?

I did

```
$ gcc -o convert -g convert
```

and then run

```
$ readelf -l convert
```

to check if the stack is executable but the output was:

```
GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x4
```

Comment: For your sanity, I hope this is for the purpose of learning about security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

`-fno-stack-protector` should do the trick for you.

Comment: You might need the `-Wl,-z,execstack` option too. (And the OP might also be interrested in [this](http://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack) )

Comment: Downvote. The stack protector flag is only vaguely related to making the stack executable.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt That is your right but : executable stack doesn't means contains executable code... OP thought that was what is was looking for but you think better than him?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Making the stack executable only makes sense if the stack will contain executable code. Neither `-fno-stack-protector` nor `-fstack-protector` make the stack executable. They add code that protects the stack against certain buffer overflows. That's a very different thing.

Comment: This Wikipedia section explains what the question is about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Nonexecutable_stack This section explains what your response is about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries Related, but different things. Your response does not answer the question.

Comment: Hint: this clearly is the accepted answer for the first comment.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to make the stack executable doesn't require that stack canaries be disabled, unlike what the accepted answer suggests.

Here's the correct way:

```
gcc -z execstack ...
```

What this does is, the `-z` option of `gcc` is passed to the linker [[source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-z)]:

> *keyword*
>
> -z is passed directly on to the linker along with the keyword *keyword*. See the section in the documentation of your linker for permitted
>   values and their meanings.

From `man ld` [[source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)]:

> **execstack**
>
> Marks the object as requiring executable stack.

Comment: The OP commented on the other answer saying that this answer "did the trick" I think its clear his comment meant that this answer was the correct one - its almost as if he accidentally accepted the wrong answer.